# gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18' fails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, gcc, rubygems, mysql2

I'm using OS X 10.9.5. Recently updated ruby to 2.2.1 and it messed up everything in my system. I'm having a hard time with this. I'm trying to do a `bundle install` on my project and it fails saying

```
Make sure that gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18' succeeds before bundling
```

I was going through the same issue yesterday. All I did was to uninstall mysql and reinstall it, then re install mysql2 and it worked. I', trying the same thing now but it wouldn't let me install mysql2.

I tried,

```
gem install mysql2 'gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'
```

Also Tried,

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18' -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

It gives me the following error,
[LInk to the error](http://pastebin.com/guM0B9WY).

I'm thinking if this could be a gcc issue. when I run `which gcc` it gives me `gcc: aliased to /usr/local/bin/cpp-4.8`. could this be the reason?

can anyone guide me in fixing this? thanks in advance

Comment: The path to mysql looks wrong.  Try `--with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql` instead.

Comment: I did a `which mysql` and it gave me `/usr/local/bin/mysql`

Comment: It is not looking for the mysql binary. It is looking for its libraries - typically under `/usr/local/mysql/lib`. If you point it to `/usr/local/mysql` it should be able to find them.

Comment: tried it, still getting the same error

Comment: your log message is not enough

try:  `brew install mysql` and then `gem install mysql`

Answer (score 3):

I got the same errors when I deploy my app to VPS(Ubuntu 14.04)

What I did to make it out is

`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Not sure for OS X , but hope this can help you.